# What is the actual cmos technology node of China and Russia not licensing major process technology from outside?

Tags: cmos, history, semiconductor-process-technology

There are a number of Russian fabs but from what I can see they are just using liscened technology ie Sitronics using STmicroelectronics at 90nm node or  Angstrem-T using AMD [see](http://www.semiconrussia.org/en/sites/semiconrussia.org/files/docs/Russia%20Market%20Update%20Nov%202012.pdf) yet in the [past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Soviet_microprocessors) there was chip equivalents made with their own technology within the Soviet countries.

The same I hear is true of China.

So what is the actual cmos technology node of China and Russia not licensing major process technology components from outside?

Comment: are you asking what ability have the Russians/Chinese to develop the chemistry needed? I think they can buy, for $10Billion, whatever machinery is needed from ASML, etc. But the chemistry may be proprietary.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  yes the chemical process steps rather than the equipment or the silicon billet - though the masks are a huge challenge in themselves.

Comment: The latest & greatest technology is export controlled due to the possibility of using it for military applications. Enough of the technology was developed in the US that even non-US companies like ASML or ST have to obey US export restrictions if they don't want to have serious trouble with the US government.

Comment: that sounds like an effective monopoly. historically monopoly does not lead to diversity and usaully leads to a development deadend.